# Can I use the office 2007 window style?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I like the Office 2007 window border (how it looks in windows XP). Is there a way to use this same border in my WPF application?

Maybe it is included in RibbonX, however the whole package seems to heavy for my application, when I only want to have the same border style.

If all this is not possible, can someone give me some advice on how to design my own border in WPF. Couldn't find much useful info on this topic..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ayakhnin/PermaLink,guid,23a7be17-d833-4e45-b498-34ef04d98cb2.aspx) article to be of interest as it shows you how to use windows style to get Office 2007 results.

It has a sample source code project with XAML that demonstrates the rounded window corners and window gradients.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a free Beta of the Office Ribbon directly from Microsoft.
I used it an WPF program already. It's not so difficult if you get used to it and it's fun. Maybe it will help you with the things you have in mind.

http://www.uxpassion.com/2008/11/download-free-wpf-ribbon-windows-scenic-office-2007-style/

http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx